# AttributeError: Numpy object 'NpzFile' has no attribute 'zip'?

Tags: python, facebook, numpy, zip

I tried to download [DrQA](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA), a system for reading comprehension applied to open-domain question answering developed by Facebook research group. It included to call for the provided trained models and data for Wikipedia question answering. Yet when I tried to launch the interactive session this `AttributeError` appeared:

```
(drqa_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA$ python scripts/pipeline/interactive.py
07/16/2018 11:38:35 PM: [ Running on CPU only. ]
07/16/2018 11:38:35 PM: [ Initializing pipeline... ]
07/16/2018 11:38:35 PM: [ Initializing document ranker... ]
07/16/2018 11:38:35 PM: [ Loading /home/mike/Programing/DrQA/data/wikipedia/docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/pipeline/interactive.py", line 83, in <module>
    tokenizer=args.tokenizer
  File "/home/mike/Programing/DrQA/drqa/pipeline/drqa.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.ranker = ranker_class(**ranker_opts)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/DrQA/drqa/retriever/tfidf_doc_ranker.py", line 37, in __init__
    matrix, metadata = utils.load_sparse_csr(tfidf_path)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/DrQA/drqa/retriever/utils.py", line 33, in load_sparse_csr
    loader = np.load(filename)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/drqa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 414, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/drqa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 173, in __init__
    _zip = zipfile_factory(fid)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/drqa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 103, in zipfile_factory
    return zipfile.ZipFile(file, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
Exception ignored in: <bound method NpzFile.__del__ of <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7fa18140e9e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/Programing/drqa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 210, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/home/mike/Programing/drqa_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 201, in close
    if self.zip is not None:
AttributeError: 'NpzFile' object has no attribute 'zip'
```

It seems to mean that Numpy object has no attribute zip. I think It tried to unzip the models file but don't have the proper tools.

Do you know how to cope with it ?  I already had problem with this repository while downloading its very large trained models repo which I talk about in [a  GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA/issues/161).

#### Update

According to abarnet, it looks like the problem is that the zipfile module can't unzip it (and then NumPy's error handling isn't quite as beautiful as it could be). It might be a corrupted file, so I tried to unzip the file that created the error:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/DrQA/data/wikipedia$ unzip -t docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz
Archive:  docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz or
        docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz.zip, and cannot find docs-tfidf-ngram=2-hash=16777216-tokenizer=simple.npz.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a corrupted file? It looks like the problem is that the `zipfile` module can't unzip it (and then NumPy's error handling isn't quite as beautiful as it could be). Can you `unzip -t` the file from your shell and verify that it's valid?

Comment: @abarnert Sure! Which one ? `npyio.py` ?

Comment: No, the `.npz` that you're trying to open, directly or indirectly—I think `simple.npz`?

Comment: @abarnert understood ! I updated the question then !

Comment: OK, so you have a corrupted (or just incomplete) .npz file. You can try to download the file again. If you get the same problem, report it upstream and hopefully someone can fix it or tell you where to get the file. If not, there’s probably nothing anyone can do for you; if the package depends on that archive, and the archive is incomplete, you just can’t use it.

Comment: @abarnert Ok, I will download these files again tonight. Its a 7.5GB tarball (25GB untarred) according to the README on GitHub, it might take some time and I wonder this huge size to download is related to the issue

Comment: It could be. Maybe try downloading it with a different tool (e.g., if you were using Firefox, try Chrome—or curl from the command line). Make sure the length of the file you get is exactly the same as the length on the server, and if they give a SHA hash or something (people often do when distributing large files), check it after the download.

Comment: Also, if you have enough disk space to keep the first download around as well as the redownload, file-compare then to make sure they’re different. That will all be useful debugging information if things fail again. (Hopefully that won’t be an issue, but better safe than sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

If this can help anyone, I got the exact same `Exception` raised...

```bash
AttributeError: 'NpzFile' object has no attribute 'zip'
```

...with Python 3.9, while trying to do the following operation...

```py
# load the file
with np.load(temp_path, allow_pickle=True) as npz_file:
    data = dict(npz_file.items())
```

...under a multiprocessing pool context...

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    # load NPZ files...
```

Dropping the multiprocessing solved my issue.